# In C++11, how can I immediately leave a function when a signal is caught?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11

In a C++11 program, I have a few functions that must stop as soon as possible (and return to the caller) every time a given unix signal is received. At first glance, an exception, thrown when the signal is received and intercepted only in the caller function, seems to be the obvious solution.

```
void sighandler(int sig) {
   throw new myexc();
}

void caller(void) {
    try {
        callee1();
        callee2();
    } catch (myexc e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But safe, portable signal-handling is rather limited as changing the value of a volatile sig_atomic_t seems to be the only correct thing to do in a signal handler. But I don't want to have my code littered with tests checking whether the sig_atomic_t has changed or not.

```
void sighandler(int sig) {
    vol = 1;
}

void callee1(void) {
    do_stuff();
    if (vol == 1) return;
    do_other_stuff();
    if (vol == 1) return;
    do_something_again();
    ...
}
```

Having a thread waiting for the value being changed then throwing an exception to be caught by the other thread does not seem to be a valid solution either.

How could I do this in a safe, portable and elegant way ?

Comment: Maybe use boost threads, they are interruptible

Comment: Perhaps use "siglongjmp" (but that will not cleanup c++ class objects...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't portablely throw an exception from a signal handler.

Not all OS actually have the appropriate stack-frame in place that is needed for stack unwinding. The best you can do is set a flag then test for this in your application.

To prevent you speckling your code with tests.
You could mkae your application into a `Reactor` then register the actual work with the reactor. Before the reactor does a new piece of work it tests to see if the signal flag has been set.

```
 Reactor   workList;

 workList.add(&callee1);
 workList.add(&callee2);

 workList.run();
```

Then inside the `Reactor`;

```
 while(notSignalled() && !list.empty());
 {
     list.head().run();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ; that's probably a clean way to deal with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure throwing an exception is allowed in a signal handler? They are completely independent from the program flow. This is also a bad design - you ought to use exceptions only in *really* exceptional circumstances.

Moreover, is full granularity of `callee1` a must? Most probably the function spends most of its time in only several chunks of code, thus there should be no need for a lot of checks for return condition.

Comment: That's right, there might be an abuse of exceptions here ; I don't know. Actually, the actual cases when the signal could be received during the treatment are pretty exceptional... Well, anyway, exceptions won't work here...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  In general, the only way to ensure prompt termination of a thread is to promptly terminate the process which contains it.  (Posix allows a bit more than the C standard in a signal: you can call `abort()` or `_exit()`, for example.  But not `exit()`.)  Otherwise... signals are asynchronous, and there is a possibility that some internal data structures (e.g. a stack frame) are not in a coherent state.